# Get my background video and image to change depending on what page(route) you are on

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to get it so depending on which page you are on the background image and video will display itself. Each page has a different image, video or both. Some are without a video.

I have tried using useEffect but keep getting an infinite render or breaking of hook rules. I have looked this up but am not too sure what I am doing wrong.

I think if I create some custom hooks it should work? But i am not sure how to do this.

Background.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import BackgroundObj from "./BackgroundObj";

import BackgroundVideo from "./BackgroundVideo";

import BackgroundImage from "./BackgroundImage";

function Background() {
  // state to set pathName to the current route location without the domain
  const [pathName, setPathName] = useState("/");
  // state to set background image
  const [picture, setPicture] = useState();
  // state to set background video
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
  // state to deconstruct object depending on what page you are on
  const [m, setM] = useState(0);

  const ChangeBackground = () => {
    // maps json array for background videos and images
    const mappedObj = BackgroundObj.map((item) => {
      return {
        image: item.image,
        video: item.video,
      };
    });
    console.log("This is mappedObj speaking, I am a... ", mappedObj);

    // using useLocation to get route loaction and re-render effect
    const location = useLocation();

    // get path name ignoring domain
    setPathName(location.pathname);
    console.log("the location is: ", location);
    console.log("getPath being called, path is: ", pathName);

    // statement to find which page you are on and set m for deconstructing the correct video and image
    switch (pathName) {
      case "/":
        setM(0);
        console.log(
          "This is the switch statement speaking, you are on the home page"
        );
        break;
      case "/activities":
        console.log(
          "This is the switch statement speaking, you are on the activities page"
        );
        setM(1);
        break;
      case "/about":
        console.log(
          "This is the switch statement speaking, you are on the about page"
        );
        setM(2);
        break;
      case "/book":
        console.log(
          "This is the switch statement speaking, you are on the book page"
        );
        setM(3);
        break;
      case "/contact":
        console.log(
          "This is the switch statement speaking, you are on the contact page"
        );
        setM(4);
        break;
      case "/privacy":
        console.log(
          "This is the switch statement speaking, you are on the privacy page"
        );
        setM(5);
        break;
      default:
        console.log("m equals", m);
    }

    // deconstructs mapped object with m, m is based on which page you are on
    const { image, video } = mappedObj[m];
    console.log(
      "This is getMapped speaking, i am deconstructing MappedObj into...",
      image,
      video
    );
    console.log("what is m after the switch statement:", m);

    // statment to check if page has a video or an image or both
    if (image === null) {
      setMovie(video);
      setPicture("");
    } else if (video === null) {
      setPicture(image);
      setMovie("");
    } else {
      setMovie(video);
      setPicture(image);
    }
    console.log("movie is set to", movie);
    console.log("picture is set to", picture);
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   ChangeBackground();
  //   // statment to check if page has a video or a video or both
  //   if (image === null) {
  //     setMovie(video);
  //     setPicture("");
  //   } else if (video === null) {
  //     setPicture(image);
  //     setMovie("");
  //   } else {
  //     setMovie(video);
  //     setPicture(image);
  //   }
  //   console.log("movie is set to", movie);
  //   console.log("picture is set to", picture);
  // }, [ChangeBackground, image, movie, picture, video]);

  return (
    <div className="fixed h-screen w-screen">
      <BackgroundVideo video={movie} />
      <BackgroundImage image={picture} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Background;
```

BackgroundImage.js

```
import React from "react";

// provides image and styling for Background
function BackgroundImage(props) {
  // sets prop for calling component in parent
  const { image } = props;
  // image background as makes div much easier to control
  return (
    <div
      className="flex items-end p-0 z-negative1 h-screen w-screen "
      style={{
        backgroundImage: `url(${image})`,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundRepeat: "norepeat",
        backgroundPosition: "bottom",
      }}
    ></div>
  );
}

export default BackgroundImage;
```

BackgroundVideo.js

```
import React from "react";

// provides video for Background and styling
function BackgroundVideo(props) {
  // sets prop for calling component in parent
  const { video } = props;

  return (
    <video
      className="absolute z-negative1 min-h-none min-w-none max-w-5xl sm:max-w-none"
      autoPlay
      loop
      muted
    >
      <source src={video} type="video/mp4" />
      Your browser does not support the video tag
    </video>
  );
}

export default BackgroundVideo;
```

BackgroundObj.js

```
import homeVideo from "../../media/videos/test_video.mp4";
import aboutVideo from "../../media/videos/test_video2.mp4";

import homeImage from "../../media/images/homeSkyline.png";

const BackgroundObj = [
  {
    key: 0,
    page: "/",
    image: homeImage,
    video: homeVideo,
  },
  {
    key: 1,
    page: "/about",
    image: "null",
    video: aboutVideo,
  },
];

export default BackgroundObj;
```

App.js

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Activities from "./pages/Activities";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";
import Book from "./pages/Book";

import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Background from "./components/background/Background";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="relative bg-night flex flex-col h-screen w-screen justify-between z-1 overflow-x-hidden">
      <Router>
        <Background />
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/activities" exact component={Activities} />
          <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
          <Route path="/book" exact component={Book} />
          <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by just calling the Background component into each page, was repeating code a bit but made it a lot easier!